# highlighting certain range of tinymce text after a button event

Tags: tinymce

Referring to a few source, and i put this into a button event,
given,

```
<textarea id="content" name="content" style="width:400px;height:100px;">
<p><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:36pt;">Some text <u>here</u> to go.</span></p>
</textarea>

var range = document.createRange();
var start = document.getElementById('tinymce');
var textNode = start.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].firstChild;
range.setStart(textNode, 1);
range.setEnd(textNode, 1);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```

but it produce error in chrome console :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

suppose i have tinymce element that generated by tinymce at first place.
any expert can help me on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that the `tinymce` id is not present in the current top level document but on the iFrame's document. So you have to first access the iFrame and get the document element.

```
var frame= document.getElementById('content_ifr');
var doc = frame.contentWindow.document;
var range = doc.createRange();
var start = doc.getElementById('tinymce');
```

find a working fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/kelvo/3krLhgcL/3/)

Comment: I tried to select character 10th to 15th but it seems like didnt work because the only the firstChild node been selected. http://jsfiddle.net/3krLhgcL/12/ any idea how to solve this?

Suspected that this issue happened because there is a <u> in that text so make it looks like 3 diff kind of nodes.

Comment: That is because `getElementsByTagName('span')[0].firstChild` returns the text node "Some text ", which has a total of 10 characters. So the end offset of 15 will throw an error since 15 is out of range. To accomplish what you are trying, you will have to do something in the lines of http://jsfiddle.net/kelvo/3krLhgcL/16/